# How to get CSRF from django in a separate React App

Tags: django, reactjs, csrf

After researching CSRF tokens and django, it's clear that the React app has to be rendered via django in order to retrieve the CSRF token normally (i.e. injected into the DOM)

The only reason I take issue with this I know instagram is using Django and React for their web app; I find it highly unlikely it's being rendered -- at least in a traditional way -- by django.

I realize it will be difficult to find an answer to how they are handling it, but perhaps someone knows a way of doing this without rendering a very large enterprise-level react app with django.

To give some perspective, our react application is in a separate repo & directory on a different subdomain to our django powered API.

We've looked for advice in every area I can think of and have yet to find a proper solution, so I appreciate any feedback you can give

Comment: Two options that come to mind: 1) construct your requests in such a way that you don't need CSRF protection at all; 2) use a dedicated CSRF endpoint to fetch the token.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenryYou should have left this as the answer, as the other respondents failed to understand the question. We took the 1st approach, unsure how good of a long term solution this is

Comment: Please consider leaving comments to clear up the confusion if the people trying to help you have misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Fush Most questions are assuming I'm using django to render the react application, which is not the case. So grabbing a non-existent cookie will not work (the two other answers). The cookie doesn't exist when the react application is first rendered. The only way I've found how to retrieve the cookie is to make something like login csrf exempt (which is not suitable I dont believe)

Comment: It's not necessary that the react app is rendered by the same app that sets the cookie. You can set the cookie on any/all API calls, and have it available to the react app from then on (assuming you work through the potential CORS issues). If you're specifically looking to be able to do it on first render, that changes things a bit, and having a dedicated csrf endpoint is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Fush That sounds awesome. So for example, the first request a user sends is a  POST to /login (example), can we just send the csrf cookie to the react client when the user does this?

Comment: @Jake I believe so, yes. It's not quite what we have in our setup so I haven't tested it. Note that the token will change when the user logs in or out.

Answer (score 1):

I used `get_token` from  `django.views.decorators.csrf` to generate a csrf token.

my django code in views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import get_token

def get_csrf(request):
    return JsonResponse({"token":get_token(request)})
```

I called this view function in react native to get a csrf token:
my reactnative code:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{ 
 fetch("api endpoint",{
 method:"GET",
 headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
 }).then((response)=>response.json())
.then((json)=>{
    //save your csrf-cookie (i use secure store to save it) 
   })
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the token from the browser cookie in JS if you need. This token is set on user log in and is valid for the lifetime of the session.

```
const csrftoken = document.cookie
    .split(';')
    .find((c) => c.trim().startsWith('csrftoken='))
    ?.replace('csrftoken=', '') as string;
```

And then use it like:

```
await fetch('/api/secure/', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    }
});
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/

Answer (score 0):

You can store the csrf token in a cookie, using [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) if necessary, and adding the header to XHR requests:

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

Request.post(url)
    .set('X-CSRFToken', Cookies.get('csrftoken'))
    .send(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can generate a csrf token like this:

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
csrf_token = get_token(request)
```

Comment: And then how do you pass this to the client (i.e. React application)?

Comment: Hi Jake, if your react app is on different subdomain ,then you can just set the CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN in settings.py to your react app url i.e react.example.com (assuming you django app's url is example.com).Then django will set csrf cookie on CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN.